# Incorrect date returned when converting from java.util.date to java.sql.date

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno, GWT and java.

When I convert

I get the date via:

```
dateBoxDOB = new DateBox();
dateBoxDOB.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, dateBoxDOB);
dateBoxDOB.getDatePicker();
```

Where I enter 20/04/1961. I then need to convert it from `java.util.date` to `java.sql.date` before saving it to MySQL:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDOB = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime());
Window.alert("Util date = " + dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime());    
Window.alert("DOB = " + sqlDOB);
java.sql.Date sqlDateArchived = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlPackIn = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxPackIn.getValue().getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlPackOut = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxPackOut.getValue().getTime());
```

The date displayed by the window alert is `-233920800000 for util` and `1962-08-04 for sql`.

How do I get the correct date please (i.e., 1961-04-20 from sql date)?

Also, if a date is null and exception is thrown. How do I get around this please?

Comment: have you tried to format the date first?first Store the dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime() in date variable then format it with the yyyy-MM-dd and then try your logic.

Comment: The conversion from uti.Date to sql.Date looks good.. Is ur client and server in different geographies ?

Comment: Sounds like you have a month/day mix-up somewhere. If the `20` in `1961-04-20` was being treated as a month instead of a day, then the date would come out as Aug 4th, 1962 (20 months is 1 year and 8 months). Double check your formats and input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me.

You are getting this issue because you defined the format as `dd-MM-yyyy` and entered date as 20/04/1961. Notice the change in format '-' vs '/'.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, you are conquistador of the code! Thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    String dateStr="20/04/1961";
    Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
    cal.setTime(date);
    Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println("utilDate:" + df.format(date));
    System.out.println("sqlDate:" + df.format(sqlDate));
```